# Button to go to List view, how to make it lightning proof

Tags: lightning

Currently there is a button on our account page that redirects the user to a list view. This button is now in URL format eg :

```
/001?fcf=00B0O000005uYKh&rolodexIndex=-1&page=1#
```

According to the lightning readiness report this behavior is no longer allowed. How should we refactor these buttons to conform?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button link and add all URL to the list view. I think that you should be able to do it like that.

Go to the ListView you want to add to the Link, copy the all URL.
Create a Detail Page Link from your Buttons, Link and Actions. 
Add URL to the Select Field Type box. 
Add button link to the page and fire the List View from there. It should work.